# How to implement copy construcuctor of smart container?

Tags: c++, pointers, copy-constructor, smart-pointers

```
struct Delete
{
     template <typename T>
     void operator() (T* t)
     {
         delete t;
     }
};

template <typename Container>
class SmartContainer
     : public Container
{
public:
     ~SmartContainer()
     {
         std::for_each(Container::begin(), Container::end(), Delete());
     }

     SmartContainer(const SmartContainer& other)
     {
         for (typename Container::const_iterator iter = other.begin(); iter != other.end(); ++iter) {
             push_back(new typename Container::value_type(**iter));
         }
     }

   SmartContainer() {}
};
```

In this code I have tried implement a smart container. The container contains pointers. It deletes the pointers when it is destroyed. The problem is in writing copy constructor. It should copy the object and put pointers of copies in the container. I am getting error in this `push_back` line because `Container::value_type` is pointer type but it needs to create an object of dereferenced type.  `std::remove_pointer` may be useful here but my compiler doesn't support c++11. Maybe a normal container with smart pointers is a better choice but I need solution for this.

Comment: It looks right to me? (so far) From `**iter` your `Container` type seems to be a pointer type, so the `push_back` is also correct. A usage example would help clarify things (http://sscce.org)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `Container::value_type` is `T*`, then `new Container::value_type` will create a `T**`.

Comment: @dyp: Oh, right :) +1 for both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement your own `remove_pointer` (from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer#Possible_implementation)):

```
template< class T > struct remove_pointer                    {typedef T type;};
template< class T > struct remove_pointer<T*>                {typedef T type;};
template< class T > struct remove_pointer<T* const>          {typedef T type;};
template< class T > struct remove_pointer<T* volatile>       {typedef T type;};
template< class T > struct remove_pointer<T* const volatile> {typedef T type;};
```

Then do `typename remove_pointer<Container::value_type>::type`.

Comment: I think you still need a `typename` before `Container::value_type`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the template parameter. Instead of `Container` make it `Container<T*>`, then you'll have the base object type available.

```
template <typename Container, typename T>
class SmartContainer
     : public Container<T*>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you mean that. With a partial specialization?

Comment: @dyp, sorry I wasn't very clear. I added an example.

Comment: In that case, `Container` needs to be a template template-parameter, `template < template<class...> class Container, class T, class... Add > class SmartContainer : public Container<T*, Add...>` (allocators etc. can be put into the `Add` parameter pack)